# Rails cache store changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memory, store

Currently I have `:memory_store` as a cache store in Rails. I want to change cache store to `:file_store`. Will memory be cleared automatically or I need to do it manually? How can I figure out how much Memory I have used using `:memory_story`? because using `Rails.cache` in `rails c` doesn't show me anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I figure out how much Memory I have used using :memory_story?
>   because using Rails.cache in rails c doesn't show me anything.

That's correct. [Memorystore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/MemoryStore.html) stores everything into memory in the same process. When running `rails c` you are starting a new process that do 
not have an access to the one, that stores data.

You can check what is the **max** size of your memorystore cache by checking the environment file. The default value is 32Mb, but it could be changed like this:

```
config.cache_store = :memory_store, :size => 64.megabytes
```

> I want to change cache store to :file_store. Will memory be cleared automatically or I need to do it manually?

I think that killing the process (aka. rails server) will clear the cache.